# Adding different value to different parts of a dataframe without loop

Tags: r

I want to speed up this calculation I need to do on specific part of the dataframe, this is an example data

```
days <- c("01.01.2018","01.01.2018","01.01.2018",
          "02.01.2018","02.01.2018","02.01.2018",
          "03.01.2018","03.01.2018","03.01.2018")
time <- c("00:00:00","01:00:00","02:00:00",
          "00:00:00","01:00:00","02:00:00",
          "00:00:00","01:00:00","02:00:00")
a <- c(1,2,3,
       1,2,3,
       1,2,3)
b <- c(1,2,3,
       5,6,7,
       10,11,12)

results <- NA

df1 <- data.frame(days,time,a,results)
df2 <- data.frame(days,time,b)
```

I need to add the value from `df2$b` at 00:00:00 of each day to the same entire day values in `df1$a` and store it in results.
Right now I'm doing it like this:

```
ndays <- unique(df1$days)

for(i in 1:length(ndays)) {
  factor <-  df2[(df2$days == ndays[i] & df2$time == "00:00:00"),]$b
  df1[df1$days == ndays[i],]$results <- df1[df1$days == ndays[i],]$a + factor

}
```

The problem is,  I've got huge dataframes with lot of days and cycling them one by one is slow. Is there a fastest way to do so?

edit: This is the filled results column after the cycle

```
df1  
        days     time a results
1 01.01.2018 00:00:00 1       2  # results = a + df$b @ 01.01.2018 00:00:00
2 01.01.2018 01:00:00 2       3  # results = a + df$b @ 01.01.2018 00:00:00
3 01.01.2018 02:00:00 3       4  # results = a + df$b @ 01.01.2018 00:00:00
4 02.01.2018 00:00:00 1       6  # results = a + df$b @ 02.01.2018 00:00:00
5 02.01.2018 01:00:00 2       7  # results = a + df$b @ 02.01.2018 00:00:00
6 02.01.2018 02:00:00 3       8  # results = a + df$b @ 02.01.2018 00:00:00
7 03.01.2018 00:00:00 1      11  # results = a + df$b @ 03.01.2018 00:00:00
8 03.01.2018 01:00:00 2      12  # results = a + df$b @ 03.01.2018 00:00:00
9 03.01.2018 02:00:00 3      13  # results = a + df$b @ 03.01.2018 00:00:00
```

Comment: What results do you expect?

Comment: i've changed the "a" column a little and added the final dataframe, i hope it's clear what i'm trying to achieve

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with a merge instead of a for loop which will be much faster. In the below answer I'm also using data.table, a fast version of data.frames that are very useful when working with large tables.

```
# install.packages("data.table")  # Uncomment if necessary
library(data.table)

df1 <- data.frame(days,time,a)  # You don't need to create the result column yet
df2 <- data.frame(days,time,b)

df1 <- data.table(df1)
df2 <- data.table(df2)

# Merge the two tables on the days column
df3 <- merge(df1, df2[time=="00:00:00"], by="days")

# This is your result
answer <- df3[, .(days, time=time.x, a, results=a+b)]
```

Output:

```
> answer
         days     time a results
1: 01.01.2018 00:00:00 1       2
2: 01.01.2018 01:00:00 2       3
3: 01.01.2018 02:00:00 3       4
4: 02.01.2018 00:00:00 1       6
5: 02.01.2018 01:00:00 2       7
6: 02.01.2018 02:00:00 3       8
7: 03.01.2018 00:00:00 1      11
8: 03.01.2018 01:00:00 2      12
9: 03.01.2018 02:00:00 3      13
```

Comment: Seems your result is not matching with OP. Have a look please.

Comment: i've changed the data after you answered, sorry bout that. Apart from that looks like the merge isn't actually adding the two values, right?

Comment: Yea. I'm surprised why your `a` value is changed. Have a look. You can resolve it and we all will have another way to solve the problem.

Comment: The answer now has your new `a` column values and does the addition you asked for.

Answer (score 2):

```
  transform(merge(df1,aggregate(b~days,df2,function(x)x[1])),results=a+b)
        days     time a results  b
1 01.01.2018 00:00:00 1       2  1
2 01.01.2018 01:00:00 2       3  1
3 01.01.2018 02:00:00 3       4  1
4 02.01.2018 00:00:00 1       6  5
5 02.01.2018 01:00:00 2       7  5
6 02.01.2018 02:00:00 3       8  5
7 03.01.2018 00:00:00 1      11 10
8 03.01.2018 01:00:00 2      12 10
9 03.01.2018 02:00:00 3      13 10
```

One thing to note. This assumes time in df2 is arranged chronologically and that the first value for any given day is of time `00:00:00`.

Answer (score 2):

One solution using `dplyr` could be as below. The approach of the solution is to:
1) First `filter` all time other than `00:00:00` from the `df2`
2) Then `inner_join` both `df1` and `df2` on `days`. This will enable to select value of `b` from `df2` to every matching `day` in merged dataframe. Finally add `a` and `b` to find `result`.

```
df1 <- data.frame(days,time,a,results, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
df2 <- data.frame(days,time,b, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

library(dplyr)

df2 %>%
  filter(time == "00:00:00") %>%
  inner_join(df1, by="days") %>%
  mutate(time = time.y, results = a+b) %>%
  select( days, time, a, b, results)

 #Result:
        days     time a  b results
1 01.01.2018 00:00:00 1  1       2
2 01.01.2018 01:00:00 2  1       3
3 01.01.2018 02:00:00 3  1       4
4 02.01.2018 00:00:00 1  5       6
5 02.01.2018 01:00:00 2  5       7
6 02.01.2018 02:00:00 3  5       8
7 03.01.2018 00:00:00 1 10      11
8 03.01.2018 01:00:00 2 10      12
9 03.01.2018 02:00:00 3 10      13
```